# Function loop that turns Array into String, while adding <option>

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, loops

I have the following function:

```
function handleResults(responseObj) {

    var dimensionValueDisplayName[];

    for (var i = 0; i < responseObj.DimensionListItem.length; i++) {
        var item = responseObj.DimensionListItem[i],
            name = item.dimensionDisplayName;
        dimensionValueDisplayName.push(name);
    }

    $("#iFilter_field").html(dimensionValueDisplayName);
}
```

;where dimensionValueDisplayName, DimensionListItem, responseObj
are all arrays of strings. responseObj is the output of an ajax function call that resolved a json data type input.

Note: #iFilter_field is the id class of an HTML dropdown Menu (above the javascript).

How can I modify my function in a way such that the Array can populate the dropdown Menu? In other words, can do I add `<option></option>` tags to every string in the resolved array?

Comment: You have a comma instead of a dot in `i < responseObj,DimensionListItem.length`

Comment: Oops that was a typo, the actual code does not have that. My apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this...

```
var field = $("#iFilter_field").empty();

for (var i = 0; i < responseObj.DimensionListItem.length; i++) {
    $('<option>').text(responseObj.DimensionListItem[i].dimensionDisplayName)
                 .appendTo(field);
}
```

jsFiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/wNhnM/

You could also get fancy with this 3-liner...

```
function handleResults(responseObj) {
    $("#iFilter_field").html(responseObj.DimensionListItem.map(function(item) {
        return $('<option>').text(item.dimensionDisplayName)[0];
    }));
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/wNhnM/1/